# FFmpeg low trim accuracy

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

So, I'm trying to cut a 1 minute 29 seconds video into clips of 30 seconds each.
The expected output is 30sec,30sec,29sec.
The result is 35sec,29sec,23sec.

This is my code -

```
 ArrayList<String> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
            commandList.add("-ss");
            commandList.add("00:00:00");
            commandList.add("-i");
            commandList.add(videoPath);
            commandList.add("-c");
            commandList.add("copy");
            commandList.add("-f");
            commandList.add("segment");
            commandList.add("-segment_time");
            commandList.add("00:00:30");
            commandList.add(TEST.getAbsolutePath());
            String[] command  = commandList.toArray(new String[commandList.size()]);
            execFFmpegBinary(command);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I read somewhere that if at a particular position a keyframe doesn't exists it seeks to position of the nearest keyframe.

Any solution or guidance will help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg will start segments on keyframes. When using `-codec copy` there is no transcode, so It must use the existing keyframes. There is no keyframe at 30s, so it cuts at the next one.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway to fix it?

Comment: I removed the `-c copy` but it takes a lot of time to trim the video.

Comment: Yes, transcoding is slow.

Comment: Is there any alternative to accomplish this? I tried using `-preset ultrafast` but no use.

Comment: Will it be efficient if I run this command - `-t  30` (in a loop) instead of  using segments?

Comment: Like first i'll run the loop from 0 to 30sec, then from 31 to 60 and so on till the end of the video.